# how can I get the data out of an .fb file?

Tags: sql, frontbase

I'm working with a company trying to setup a new database system as their old database software has gone out of business. All the data is in a .fb file that is encrypted (You used to have to get backups 'unlocked' before they would let you use them).

I've managed to get a copy of the database (I think it's unencrypted as I copied it while the database was open and then changed the copied files permissions using terminal).

The problem is that it's a .fb file and I can't find a way to 'open' it to browse the data...

Any Ideas?

Comment: Being completely unfamiliar with frontbase or `.fb` files... what does it look like in a text editor?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, data stored in relational databases aren't just stored as ascii csv files. So you won't be able to just open up a .fb file in a text editor and grab the data.

If you're still able to query the database, you will need to have the frontbase server generate a dump of the data into a flat file.

See the frontbase documentation for [backup and restore](http://www.frontbase.com/docs/4.9.html). Specifically `4.9.1. Exporting Schema and Content Data`:

```
WRITE ALL OUTPUT('<output-directory>' [,'YES']);
```